# Twitter Search API - PHP multiple word search not working

Tags: forms, search, twitter

I have a simple search bar, user types in a search terms and tweets that match the search terms should show up. However, it only works for single word searches.

```
<div id="search">
<form action="" method="get">
  <label>
  Search:
  <input type="text" name="search_box" id="search_box" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
  </label>
</form>
</div>

<?php 


$q=$_GET['search_box'];

$search = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=".$q."";

$tw = curl_init();

curl_setopt($tw, CURLOPT_URL, $search);
curl_setopt($tw, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$twi = curl_exec($tw);
$search_res = new SimpleXMLElement($twi);

echo "<h3>Twitter search results for '".$q."'</h3>";

foreach ($search_res->entry as $twit1) {

$description = $twit1->content;

$message = $row['content'];

echo "<div class='text'>".$description."</div><br><br>";

}

curl_close($tw);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're searching with quotation marks for exact phrase matches then you need to escape these quotes before constructing your query string. With the current code:

```
$q = $_GET['q']
$search = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=".$q."";
```

the input "test phrase" will result in this expression (which will probably cause a parse error):

`"http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q="test phrase"";`

Instead, try urlencoding the user input before including it in the search string:

```
$q = urlencode($_GET['q']);
$search = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q={$q}";
```

Which should result in the value:

`http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%22test%20phrase%22`

You can check that this works by entering the URL in your browser.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem :) Do you know how I could add an extra word onto every search query? ex: searching "happy hour" will in fact search "happy hour friday", searching "sad hour" will in fact search "sad hour friday".

Comment: It ended up only working for the test case I was using. I had been searching "angry birds as my test query, which was biased because those two words almost always appear directly next to each other (at least on twitter). I ended up finding the right answer.

Comment: Yes, I explained about keyword matching in my other answer. I don't see why you've unmarked this as the solution to this question though...

Comment: I gave it back as a thank you, but the one I have below is the one that I used.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Here's the best resource for the Twitter Search API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

For matching exact phrases, simply wrap the query string in qoutes.

--

In the Twitter API, any phrases are logicals ANDs, while comma separated values are logical ORs.

> "Comma separated keywords and phrases are logical ORs, phrases are logical ANDs.
>   Words within phrases are delimited by spaces. A tweet matches if any phrase matches.
>   A phrase matches if all of the words are present in the tweet. (e.g. the twitter is the
>   AND twitter, and the,twitter is the OR twitter.). Terms are exact-matched, and also
>   exact-matched ignoring punctuation."

This is actually from the Streaming API but I believe that it also applied to the search API (somebody please correct me if I'm wrong!).

Let's consider what this means for a trivial example:

```
Tweet: "This is a tweet about grapefruit"
```

Will be matched with query:

- tweet
- grapefruit
- tweet grapefruit

but not with:

- pineapple
- grapefruit pineapple

If you were searching for tweets wither either "pineapple" or "grapefruit" in, then your query parameter would need to be:

"grapefruit,pineapple".

Comment: I'd like to have it so that a user can search "tweet about grapefruit" and have it return tweets that match the exact phrase. That means I need to pass in the phrase w/ the quotes. What would I pass as the variable $q in order to make that work?

Comment: I don't think there is any way of matching exact phrases with the Twitter API. If you passed the string "tweet about grapefruit", it would still match the text "This is a tweet about how much I love grapefruit".

Comment: I just checked the documentation and it gives this example : GET http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Twitter%20API&result_type=mixed

Comment: Yes. So the search "Twitter API" matches this tweet: "This must be something like twitter jail...*reached API limit". This shows there is no exact phrase matching.

Comment: Under search operators on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search it  says you can use quotes like "happy hour" --> containing the exact phrase "happy hour".

Comment: You're right. I think you just answered your own question then. Wrap the query string in quotes for exact phrases. I've updated the answer to include the API docs for other people. If this still isn't working then try to provide an example in the question.

Comment: When type "happy hour" (with quotes) into my search box, it doesn't work, but I feel it's just something wrong with my setup. Does it look that way?

Comment: I've added a new answer which should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = $_GET['search_box']." is";
$search = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%22".urlencode( $q )."%22";
```